# The proper use of MSXML replaceChild

Tags: xml, msxml

I'm trying to replace a node in one XML document with a node from another XML document. I'm getting the following error:

```
Insert position node must be a Child of the node to insert under.
```

This is a simplified version of my XML:
XMLDOC1

```
<pages>
  <page id="1">
     <content>First Document</content>
  </page>
</pages>
```

The other XML document is the exact same in structure:
XMLDOC2

```
<pages>
  <page id="1">
     <content>Second Document</content>
  </page>
</pages>
```

I need to replace the page node of the first document with the page node of the second document. My attempt looks like this:

```
firstNode = xmlDoc1.selectSingleNode("//page[@id=1]")
secondNode = xmlDoc2.selectSingleNode("//page[@id=1]")
xmlDoc1.replaceChild(firstNode, oldNode)
```

Thanks.

**Solution**

```
firstNode.parentNode.replaceChild(xmlDoc1.importNode(secondNode, true), firstNode)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of the `replaceChild` is:

```
var objXMLDOMNode = oXMLDOMNode.replaceChild(newChild, oldChild);
```

- `newChild` - An object. The address of the new child that is to replace the old child. If Null, oldChild is removed without a replacement.
- `oldChild` - An object. The address of the old child that is to be replaced by the new child.

It looks like you have to **reverse your arguments**. And the node that you run the `replaceChild()` on should be the **parent** of the node you're replacing. You shouldn't be running it on the `document`. And finally, since you're replacing with a node from a different document you should first **import** it with the `xmlDoc1.importNode(secondNode, true)`. You can also consider `cloning` the node with `cloneNode(deep)` before using it in a new context (just so that you had a copy of your own).

p.s. shouldn't it be `secondNode` and not the `oldNode` in your code snippet?

Comment: Yes, there was a typo. I updated my code and it works perfectly (see updated question). Thanks for the clarification on the importNode bit; I noticed that somewhere else, but wasn't sure why.